# Iterating over array references causes infinite looping

Tags: arrays, perl, loops

I have the following method:

```
sub CleanErrorLog {
  my ($actnList, $cmplist) = @_;


  print "\n" . ("-" x 100) . "\n";
  print "\t\t---->>  Begin Clean Error Output  <<----";
  for my $comp (@$cmplist)
  { 
    for my $action (@$actnList)
    { 
        Build($comp, $action);
    }
  }
}
```

This is called by:

```
CleanErrorLog(\@actionList, \@failedComponents) if @failedComponents;
```

However, the loop never ends - it continuously attempt to `Build($comp, $action)` over and over. This is the first time I've used `\@` for parameters, so I could be doing something wrong?

Comment: How many items are in each of these lists? Also for debugging, replace the Build function call with a print statement where you print out those two variables.

Comment: For debugging: Does it work with `CleanErrorLog([@actionList], [@failedComponents])`? In that case, `Build` would be modifying `@actionList` or `@failedComponents` which could cause an infinite loop.

Comment: No endless loop here, https://eval.in/141986

Comment: @amon Using `[@actionlist], [@failedComponents]` worked - thanks, I see the problem now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Build` function probably modified the `@actionList` or `@failedComponents` arrays. As you passed your arrays by reference, these modifications could lead to infinite looping. As a guide line, never modify the array or hash you are iterating over. Always do a copy first. For example, you could pass copies to `CleanErrorLog`:

```
CleanErrorLog([@actionList], [@failedComponents]) if @failedComponents;
```

The better solutution would be to rework `Build` so that it doesn't modify these variables.